# Visual Studio 2012 Express and Professional

Tags: visual-studio

If I create an MVC 4 project in VS 2012 Web Express and then open it in VS 2012 Professional. Will I be able to then open it again in VS 2012 Web Express? The reason I ask is that I have VS 2012 Professional on my Home Desktop but only VS 2012 Web Express on my Home Laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should not be a problem. My understanding is that one of the only real differences between the two editions is the lack of plugin support in express.